# problem : point cloud2 in rviz

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

I have irobot create & kinect and i try to do this tutorial  [Visualizing TurtleBot 3D camera Data](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/pre_groovy/Looking%20at%20Camera%20Data)
and i have done every thing correctly but when i tried to Add a PointCloud2 View there is no thing appears
can anyone tell me ,what is the problem ?

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54028/problem-:-point-cloud2-in-rviz/) by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-02-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try rostopic echo /camera/depth/points .. if u seen data is being transferred then u might have to adjust some settings in rviz related to tf..

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-02-15**:
@shade
it seems to be problem with tf , u know how can i adjust it ?

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-02-15**:
Can u elaborate problem with tf. Use tf_echo to check transformation between frame_id of camera_depth_points and constant frame like map/world  or maybe odom. Are u seeing points when u echo /camera/depth/points??

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure you run **$rosrun dynamic_reconfigure reconfigure_gui**, select `camera/driver` from the list and tick the box for debth_registration. In rviz, change your PointCloud2 topic to`/camera/depth_registered/points`   and also you will see color transformation below the topic, set it to rgb8. make sure your fixed frame is set to `/camera_depth_optical_frame`.

---

Originally posted by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) with karma: 735 on 2013-02-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-02-02**:
Thank you ..i will try this :)

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-02-13**:
@K_Yousif
it is not possible to set color transformation to rgb8 and still there is no cloud point